# Link to market on my Android PreferencesScreen

Tags: android, xml, hyperlink, android-preferences

1) I would like to create a link (e.g : //market.android.com/details?id=com.myAPP) on my preference screen when the user select the following item :

```
<PreferenceScreen
        android:key="linkToMarket"
        android:summary="Click here to give an opinion about this app."
        android:title="Give my opinion" >
</PreferenceScreen>
```

How can I do that ?

2) I would like to print some text in my preference screen. What object should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To launch the Play Store page for you app use the following line of code. You probably want to place this in the onClick method for your `Preference`.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.package.name")));
```

2) I guess you just want to use `Preference` here. For more detailed information on how to layout preference screens, have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I have place your code in onCLick method and it's works fine.